# Jade conditional logic is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

```
 table
 tr(ng-repeat="(key1,val1) in val")
   -var imageCheck="{{key1}}"
   if (imageCheck=='image') 
        td #{imageCheck}
        td {{val1}}
```

In above code, `imageCheck` value is printing if we don't use with `if` condition, but it's not printing if we used with `if` condition.

I have tried:

```
  if(#{imageCheck}='image')
```

Not working.

Comment: because the condition fails as you've changed the variable in the previous line.

Comment: didn't get your point? can you elaborate

Comment: pls show your `val` object and what you want?

Comment: why it is not working in jade

Answer (score 2):

just use it may solve your problem

```
table
      tr(ng-repeat='(key1, val1) in val')
        td(ng-if="key1 === 'image'") {{val1}}
        td(ng-if="key1 !== 'image'") no Image found //or default image
```

Comment: what about if else condition??

Comment: else condition need ?

Comment: yes shaishab, if image then i need to display else default image has to display. val object contains a array object

Comment: add not condition  `td(ng-if="key1 !== 'image'")`  for default image

Comment: Thanks a lot, shaishab, if you have any inputs regarding why it is not working in jade, please give

Comment: `var val = {
    '120x360' : {
        'image' : 'image URL',
        'lp' : 'LP'
    },
    '120x260' : {
        'image' : 'image url',
        'lp' : 'LP'
    }
};`

Comment: under your question comment you said `val` is an array now you shown here `val` is an object :),  If you want to solve your problem please clearly describe your problem and what you want and what your real data (by edit your question not in comment section).Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91289/discussion-between-shaishab-roy-and-chethu).